# Were the entity sets and their associated relationships accurately and properly constructed?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

To be considered:
The bolded terms that appear across the requirement I laid out bellow are the ones included in the entity set (Vehicle) I created.
I also specified the attributes nature/kind/type.

Consider a database for department of motor vehicles (the “dreaded” DMV).
In this database, each vehicle has a **make** and a **model**, and a **unique vehicle
identification number**(1_VEH_NUM). For the purposes of DMV, a vehicle can be either a
**two-wheel vehicle**(2-wheel-veh) or a (4-wheel-veh)**four-wheel vehicle**(or neither).

DMV further defines **cars**(composite attribute) and **race cars**(composite attribute) as special types of four-wheel vehicles. It is possible that a race car is also a (regular) car (and vice-versa) -  *i.e., this vehicle is licensed to be driven on public roads and as well as on a race track*.DMV does not consider four-wheel vehicles that are not (regular) cars or race cars.

DMV keeps track of **licenses plate numbers**(component attributes) for all two-wheel vehicles and four-wheel vehicles (but not for race cars). For race cars, **a safety index**(component attributes) (a value between 1 and 10) and a **class**(component attributes)(e.g., WRC (Rally), Formula 1, etc)
needs to be stored in the database. DMV also stores the **maximum number of persons**(component attributes; maximum_persons) that are allowed to be carried in each four-wheeled vehicle.

Try to establish a E-R Diagram that accurately depicts the presented scenario.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqwpI.png)

I considered the **Vehicles** an entity set which encompasses the following attributes:
1_VEH_NUM(primary key)
make
model

The entity set **Vehicles** participates to the relationship set through **2-wheel-veh** and **4-wheel-veh** which establish the connection with **Vehicle_Types** entity set. The aforementioned entity set contains a primary-key composite attribute - **type** and its related neighbor **maximum_persons**(this is questionably as I don't really know whether a primary could be even a composite attribute or not).

The cardinality of 4-wheel-veh is total on both sides as both type of 4 wheel vehicles could be either race or regular.
As for the 2-wheel-veh relationship I perceived it as having a one-to-one cardinality especially because there's a single way to uniquely identify these ones - license plate.

Comment: It is a difficult question to parse: you might want to rewrite more schematically.  That said, it seems to me you are asking how to model "database (table) inheritance": try a search on this site as there should already be few answers about that.

Comment: I will check on the source you've suggested as quickly as I possibly can.